# Adding list to Map object in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I need to add a list to a map object in groovy. However, it fails  when I execute this statement docList.add(Doc). If I create a class and add the class object to a list it works, but the JsonBuilder messes w/ the field ordering when using class objects, so I'm trying to use a map list instead. Any ideas?

```
Map Doc = [
    docName : "",
    docType : ""
];

Map Name = [
    firstName : "",
    lastName : "",
    middleName : "",
    documents : docList
];

Map<String,Object> docList = []
Doc.docName= "test"
Doc.docType= "docx"
docList.add(Doc);

println new JsonBuilder(Name).toPrettyString();
```

I expect to create following JSON document:

```
{
    "firstName" : "",
    "lastName" : "",
    "middleName" : "",
    "documents": [
        {
            "docName" : "test"
            "docType" : "docx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code throws

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.util.Map' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Map()
```

because you have assigned an empty list to a map in this line:

```
Map<String,Object> docList = []
```

Replace it with `List` and reorganize the code (so the `docList` gets initialized before `name`) and it will work:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

Map doc = [
        docName: "",
        docType: ""
]

List docList = []
doc.docName = "test"
doc.docType = "docx"
docList.add(doc)

Map name = [
        firstName : "",
        lastName  : "",
        middleName: "",
        documents : docList
]

println new JsonBuilder(name).toPrettyString()
```

Output:

```
{
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "middleName": "",
    "documents": [
        {
            "docName": "test",
            "docType": "docx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I was using the List type before, but moving the List def before the Name Map was the main issue. Thanks again for saving me time.

Answer (score 0):

Your doclist is `Map` and you are treating like a `List`

```
List docList = []

Doc.docName= "test"
Doc.docType= "docx"
docList.add(Doc);
```

Should work